# Changing colour of existing geom, with no grouping

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is likely just a blunder from my side, not remembering how to do this. Non-the-less. Imagine a scenario where you have a function generating a `ggplot`. You give no grouping, and the points are all coloured black. For simplicity, imagine the plot below is the one returned.

```
library(ggplot2)
data(mtcars)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(y = mpg, x = hp)) + 
      geom_point()
```

How would I now change the colour of the points in `p`, without modifying the function that generated the plot itself. Eg. changing the code to `geom_point(col = "green")` would **not** be the an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easy way to do it is to add a dummy aesthetic mapping after the fact:

```r
 p + aes(color = "forestgreen") + scale_color_identity(guide = guide_none())
```

[image]

A more permanent alternative, which is the equivalent of going back and writing the `color = "forestgreen"` parameter back into the `geom_point` call is:

```r
p$layers[[1]]$aes_params <- list(colour = "forestgreen")
```

Comment: Thanks Allan, that is definitely the simplest way. I'll have to wait another 8 minutes before accepting it though. Could change `scale_color_identity` with `guides(col = guide_none())` as well.

Comment: @Oliver I have added an alternative which might be even closer to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to create a `ggplot_build` object, modify it directly, and rebuild the `ggplot` object:

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(y = mpg, x = hp)) +
       geom_point()
q <- ggplot_build(p)
q$data[[1]]$colour <- "cornflowerblue"
p <- ggplot_gtable(q)
plot(p)
```

[image]

Comment: You _can_ do it by manipulating the ggplot object directly (see the footnote on my answer), but that's not quite what you're doing here, since calling `ggplot_build` produces an object of class `"ggplot_built"`, not `"ggplot"`, so it loses some of the extensibility. Incidentally, great to have you back answering questions here. Looking forward to seeing some more of your answers!

Comment: That's a fair clarification, I've edited my answer. I was hunting around in the ggplot object and couldn't find it in `p$layers[[1]]$geom$aesthetics` and gave up, but your approach is much easier.